# Map Json to custom class

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have following json:

```
{"EventMessageUId":"ef51b5a3-32b2-e611-baf9-fc3fdb446bd2","Message":
"{\"StoryId\":20500,\"StoryDesc\":\"Test Story
data\"}","ProjectId":"1"}
```

Below is the class in which I'm trying to map it:

```
public class Requirments
    {

        public int FileID { get; set; }
        public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        public List<Message> Message { get; set; }
        //public object[] Message { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }
```

It is taking message tag as a string

```
  "Message": "{\"StoryId\":20500,\"StoryDesc\":\"Test Story data\"}"
```

I want to Map it into `List<Message>`

```
 public class Message
    {
        public string StoryID { get; set; }
        public string StoryDesc { get; set; }
    }
```

What can I do for this without changing json?

In the current scenario it gives me an error when I try it with `List<Message>`

Comment: What JSON deserialiser are you using, and where is the code relating to this?

Comment: requirements objRequirement = JsonObject.ToObject<requirements>();  I am using Newtonsoft Json @G0dsquad

Comment: your json doesn't have Message as a collection. Collections should be wrapped in square brackets e.g. "Message":[{"field":"value"}, {"field":"value"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
string jsonstr = File.ReadAllText(YourJSONFile);
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("\"{", "{");
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("}\"", "}");
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("\\", "");
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMessages>(jsonstr);
```

The classes would look like

```
public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("StoryId")]
    public int StoryId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("StoryDesc")]
    public string StoryDesc { get; set; }
}

public class MyMessages
{
    [JsonProperty("Message")]
    public Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with the JSON is

```
"Message": "{\"StoryId\":20500,\"StoryDesc\":\"Test Story data\"}"
           ^                                                   ^
```

are these `"` which is making it a string instead of two different properties of JSON. So we removed that `"{` and `}"` with

```
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("\"{", "{");
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("}\"", "}");
```

and now the remaining JSON string will be

```
"Message": {\"StoryId\":20500,\"StoryDesc\":\"Test Story data\"}
            ^        ^        ^          ^  ^                ^
```

in which we have `\` back slash in the JSON string which will again creates issue while deseralizing the JSON string. So

```
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("\\", "");
```

Comment: This looks promising.. let me try

Comment: this should do the trick, but keep in mind that the replacement of \", \{, }\ is for the complete String not only the message part. The cleanest option would be changing the dataformat.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different problems in deserializing your JSON to your `Requirments` class:

1. The `Message` property contains nested double-serialized data.  I.e. the sending system serialized the original `Message` object to a JSON string then included that in an outer container object that was subsequently itself serialized, causing the inner JSON data to be escaped.
2. The nested JSON represents a single object - a collection of name/value pairs surrounded by braces.  But you want to deserialize to a `List<Message>`, and all JSON serializers will map a `List<T>` to a JSON array rather than to a JSON object.

Both these problems can be overcome by using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) combined with a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for the `Message` property.  However, the conversion will require two independent steps:

1. You will need to unwrap the nested double-serialized JSON into a string.
2. And then map the JSON object thereby unwrapped with a converter similar to `SingleOrArrayConverter<T>` from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n).

The following set of converters performs this chained conversion:

```
public class SingleOrArrayConverter<TCollection, TItem> : SingleOrArrayConverter where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (!base.CanConvert(objectType))
            return false;
        return typeof(TCollection).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}

public class SingleOrArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.IsArray || objectType == typeof(string) || objectType.IsPrimitive)
            return false;
        Type elementType = null;
        foreach (var type in objectType.GetCollectItemTypes())
        {
            if (elementType == null)
                elementType = type;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return elementType != null;
    }

    object ReadJsonGeneric<TItem>(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var collection = (ICollection<TItem>)(existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            serializer.Populate(reader, collection);
        else
            collection.Add(serializer.Deserialize<TItem>(reader));
        return collection;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (objectType.IsArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Read-only collections such as arrays are not supported");
        try
        {
            var elementType = objectType.GetCollectItemTypes().SingleOrDefault();
            if (elementType == null)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("{0} is not an ICollection<T> for some T", objectType));
            var method = typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter).GetMethod("ReadJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            return method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType }).Invoke(this, new object[] { reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Wrap the TargetInvocationException in a JsonSerializerException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to deserialize " + objectType, ex);
        }
    }

    void WriteJsonGeneric<TItem>(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (ICollection<TItem>)value;
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            foreach (object item in list)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var objectType = value.GetType();
        try
        {
            var elementType = objectType.GetCollectItemTypes().SingleOrDefault();
            if (elementType == null)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("{0} is not an ICollection<T> for some T", objectType));
            var method = typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter).GetMethod("WriteJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType }).Invoke(this, new object[] { writer, value, serializer });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Wrap the TargetInvocationException in a JsonSerializerException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to serialize " + objectType, ex);
        }
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetCollectItemTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

public class StringConverterDecorator : JsonConverterDecorator
{
    public StringConverterDecorator(Type jsonConverterType) : base(jsonConverterType) { }

    public StringConverterDecorator(JsonConverter converter) : base(converter) { }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        // Unwrap the double-serialized string.
        var s = JToken.Load(reader).ToString();
        var token = JToken.Parse(s);
        // Then convert the revealed JSON to its final form.
        using (var subReader = token.CreateReader())
        {
            while (subReader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
                subReader.Read();
            return base.ReadJson(subReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string s;

        // Serialize the value to an intermediate JSON string.
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var subWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
            {
                base.WriteJson(subWriter, value, serializer);
            }
            s = textWriter.ToString();
        }
        // Then double-serialize the value by writing the JSON as a string literal to the output stream.
        writer.WriteValue(s);
    }
}

public abstract class JsonConverterDecorator : JsonConverter
{
    readonly JsonConverter converter;

    public JsonConverterDecorator(Type jsonConverterType) : this((JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(jsonConverterType)) { }

    public JsonConverterDecorator(JsonConverter converter)
    {
        if (converter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return converter.CanConvert(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return converter.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        converter.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return converter.CanRead; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return converter.CanWrite; } }
}
```

Then apply the chained converter to your `Message` property using a [`[JsonConverter(typeof(TConverter), ...)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) attribute as follows:

```
public class Requirments
{
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringConverterDecorator), typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter))]
    public List<Message> Message { get; set; }

    public string error { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize with [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm):

```
var requirement = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requirments>(jsonString);
```

Or, if you do not want to apply the converter to directly to your type, you can add it to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) and deserialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new StringConverterDecorator(new SingleOrArrayConverter<List<Message>, Message>()) },
};
var requirement = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requirments>(json, settings);
```

Note the generic `SingleOrArrayConverter<List<Message>, Message>` is required here to prevent the converter from applying to all types of collection.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EuxaEV).

Comment: Can it be implemented with NewtonSoft Json ??

Comment: @CSharper - yes, the above implementation uses NewtonSoft Json's [tag:json.net].

Comment: When I remove line :- [JsonConverter(typeof(StringConverterDecorator), typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<Message>))]   It gices me error :-   Error converting value "{"StoryId":20500,"StoryDesc":"Test Story data"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ATL.Trebuchet.Requirement.Message]'. Path 'Message'

Comment: @CSharper Why did you remove the `[JsonConverter]` attribute?  That is required to allow this solution to work correctly.

Comment: @CSharper - OK, there was a problem with the original answer if you added the converter to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` rather than applying directly to the property.   I updated the answer to make both options work.  New sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EuxaEV

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the `Message` class is right. However the Json body for `message` property is not an array. So the class should be

```
public class Requirments
{

    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    //public object[] Message { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: public Message Message { get; set; }  this does not work

Comment: please change the `Message` class name to something else. The problem is the PropertyName and class both are same

Comment: Aah your json `Message` property is _**escaping the double quotes_**. From where are you getting the Json response?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is with your JSON, it should look like this

```
{"EventMessageUId":"ef51b5a3-32b2-e611-baf9-fc3fdb446bd2","Message":
[{"StoryId":20500,"StoryDesc":"Test Story
data"}],"ProjectId":"1"}
```

After that you will get "Message" as a list, and also you can easily map it to class.

```
public class Message
{
    public int StoryId { get; set; }
    public string StoryDesc { get; set; }
}

public class Requirments
{
    public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Message { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have already mentioned in question :- What can I do for this without changing json?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully parsed list of class type **Message** from your Json but for that you will slightly need to change your class **Requirements**:

```
public class Requirments
    {    
        public int FileID { get; set; }
        public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string  Message { get; set; } 
        //public List<Message> Message { get; set; } // **need to change property type to "string"**
        //public object[] Message { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }
```

You can try below code:

```
Requirments mainResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requirments>("YOUR JSON STING");
List<Message> MessageList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(mainResult.Message.ToString());
```

Note: you will need to include **using Newtonsoft.Json;** in your class.

This will give you list of class type **Message** in **MessageList**

Hope, this will help!